# GetFile size from HttpClient.GetStreamAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How to retrieve the size of the file that i m getting with my `HttpClient` before returning the `fileStreamResult`

```
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> Index(string id)
    {
        var urlToDownloadFromService= _upDownService.Downloadables.Find(d => d.Name == id);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(new Uri(urlToDownloadFromService.UrlSource));
        var fileStreamResult =  new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
        return fileStreamResult;
    }
```

`stream.Length` doesn't work because `ContentLengthReadStream` doesnt implement the method

**UPDATE**

In dotnetcore framework the implementation of `HttpConnection` take the length information from the `response` object like so

```
else if (response.Content.Headers.ContentLength != null)
{
     long contentLength = Response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault();
.
.
.
.

     responseStream = new ContentLengthReadStream(this, (ulong)contentLength);
```

[Github source httpConnection](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/8fa7094c5609b496cedf742359fe779335e9bb8e/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnection.cs#L635)

Comment: The remote site may not be supplying the length either; streaming without a `Content-Length` is allowed and making assumptions about the internals is unwise. If `.Length` won't work, drop down to `GetAsync` and peel the header (and the stream) from the `HttpResponseMessage`, so you can forward it when it's present.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for the information, what assumptions are you talking about ?

Comment: The fact that `ContentLengthReadStream` exists (and what it implements) is an internal detail; the type isn't public. Implementing `.Length` would be technically possible, but unwise, because supporting this should mean (per the docs) that the stream is seekable, which it's not. If `Stream.CanSeek` is `false`, the docs specify that `.Length` should also throw (even though there's no inherent contradiction in having an unseekable stream with a known length, but them's the breaks). Because the length is always optional, it'd be awkward to use anyway.

Comment: thanks for the information so there's a way to get the size ?

Comment: Sure, you see it yourself in the source: get an `HttpResponseMessage` by calling `.GetAsync` and access the `ContentLength` header (if it exists). `GetStreamAsync` is just a convenience method for not having to call `HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()` method does not support the HTTP `Content-Length`, reported by the HTTP server as a header of the HTTP protocol.

So, you can't get the file size with `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()`.

I suggest using `HttpClient.GetAsync()` method. The result is a `HttpResponseMessage`.

There you can get the file size with `HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength` before getting the stream.

But not every HTTP server reports the HTTP `Content-Length`. So maybe, this value is `0` instead of the file size;

The stream, you can get with `HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStream()`.